# selected html elements into global object to avoid duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery

I one day was thinking that I could remove duplication of id this way:

```
htmlElements = {
    $tabs: jQuery('#tabs'),
    $tabs1: jQuery('#tabs-1'),
};
```

and in javascript when need to acceess - use htmlElements.$tabs for example. I was thinking - if the design needs to be changed, it the designers might use different ids and we will need to change things either in design or in javascript code to replace all ids. And this way we would need to replace in one place.

Is it too hardcore or good thing? Cannot find on internet questions about this.

I think I decided to do this after I saw that backbone has $el in the object.

Comment: Yes, what you're doing (caching selectors) is a good thing but not necessarily in the global scope. It depends.

Comment: caching is to improve speed as I understand. But speed is not the main concern, there is no any problems with speed. I am htinking of what is more maintanable and readable.